# ajax in the spring mvc + thymeleaf application

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm playing around with spring mvc + thymeleaf.

However I'd like to have integration with ajax (partial page rendering).

Can you recommend me some sample code/tutorial to follow?

I've only found following:

- spring mvc + thymeleaf + spring web flow + apache tiles + spring javascript (http://blog.springsource.org/2013/03/26/bringing-new-life-to-spring-travel-with-thymeleaf/)
- spring mvc + apache tiles + spring javascript (http://maciekmoczkowski.blogspot.de/2009/09/partial-rendering-with-spring-mvc-and.html)

however I'm not interested in using apache tiles or spring web flow at all.

Comment: Once your page is rendered, you don't need thymeleaf anymore. You can use javascript to directly modify html elements.

Comment: you're right, however I'm trying to keep my solution with as few javascript as possible. Therefor I tried to prevent some javascript + ajax retrieving data from server via JSON + replacing page fragments. but rather I'd like to use the beauty of Spring javascript, as full page reload is considered as a fallback only and in case, there is a javascript decoration available, it takes care of particular page fragment only.

Comment: Very useful article: http://xpadro.blogspot.ru/2014/02/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiles is mandatory, for this purpose - according to the site documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-js.html#spring-js-ajax

Refer section titled - "12.5. Handling Ajax Requests"

This link tells you what is needed is just a parameter with your request, named fragments
http://brosan.net/2012/09/25/partials-with-spring-mvc-3-1-and-apache-tiles/